# How to drop duplicates in each group in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function, group-by

I have the following dataset:

```
id1   id2     value
a1    b1     "main"
a1    b1     "main"
a1    b1     "secondary"
a2    b2     "main"
a2    b2     "repair"
a2    b2     "uploaded"
a2    b2     "main"
```

I want to drop duplicate values in the column called `value` in each `id1` and `id2` group. So the desired result is:

```
id1   id2     value
a1    b1     "main"
a1    b1     "secondary"
a2    b2     "main"
a2    b2     "repair"
a2    b2     "uploaded"
```

How could I do that? I know the method `drop_duplicates`, but how can I use it with `groupby`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = (
    df.groupby(["id1", "id2"])
    .apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates("value"))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  id1 id2        value
0  a1  b1       "main"
1  a1  b1  "secondary"
2  a2  b2       "main"
3  a2  b2     "repair"
4  a2  b2   "uploaded"
```